# Outlook.com sends emails to deleted group members

Tags: outlook.com

I deleted a member from a group and it no longer appears on the group list. But when a send an email to the group it is also sent to the deleted member

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your browser has cached certain information (such as the members of this group). Clearing your browser cache will solve this issue.